# Someone advised not to edit my question since it would invalidate existing answers, but I don't believe it does. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

Because [editing questions invalidates answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837983/do-winapi-libraries-have-namespaces?noredirect=1#comment85576890_48837983), as said by a moderator in the comments. However in the ["How can I get out of a question ban"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) reading hosted on the official site, it was ***recommended*** to improve existing questions.

Often times I'll end up spending 1 to several hours trying to conjure up a *good* question for SO, only to be blindsided by a wave of down votes within the first 10 minutes, damning every second I spent in research and revision to be in vain.

What should I do now?

Comment: I disagree with their premise that you substantially changed your question and invalidated previous answers.. your edit didn't (as far as I can tell), change the original question. It looks fine to me, though admittedly I have no experience in that area. I've pinged IInspectable for clarification, and let them know about this meta post.

Comment: I didn't notice earlier - there is no use clarifying that you are aware of *I am fully aware that C doesn't contain namespaces*. I over looked it - but it shouldn't be. This is something which invalidates part of the answer I suppose. That's why I deleted the answer here. Supposedly your edit shouldn't do it.

Comment: (There is no moderator here.  This is an answerer believing that you had over-edited your question.  I'm not seeing this and a handful of others aren't either.)

Comment: While it's true that we're told not to make edits that invalidate answers, I've also been told that it's OK for an edit to invalidate answers if the edit clarifies an unclear question because users shouldn't be answering questions they thought were clear but aren't. Basically, I don't think there is a consensus on where the line is.

Comment: It is very unclear why you thought that editing the **answer** would help you get out of a question ban.  It just doesn't and the answer is quite correct as posted.  Any SO user would and should rollback that edit.  He did not rollback your edits to the question, he merely reminded you that changing history has its limitations.

Comment: @BSMP Well, what do you think is more fair? The latter case, don't you think? It'd be saddening if you can't right a wrong because somebody else did wrong.

Comment: @Gimby: Except, the initial question was clear, and the edit only succeeded in making it less clear. While invalidating a correct and valid answer along the way. There was no wrong that needed to be 'righted'. The net result now is: An unclear question with a fairly useless answer. I doubt that this is in the spirit of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Makoto: As much as I respect feedback, it requires domain-specific knowledge to make the call of whether the edit changed the question. It appears that all users with that domain-specific knowledge, who have responded, are in agreement, that the edit went wrong. There are so many other users responding, that do not have that domain-specific knowledge, giving the impression, that the majority thinks, this were OK. That majority, though, is speculating at best.

Comment: @IInspectable That may be so, that was not under discussion in the exchange you pinged yourself into.

Comment: @Gimby: I don't know, what *"that"* is, so I cannot comment on whether this was *"under discussion"* or not. You'd need to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The OP did the right thing, for the wrong reasons. The motivation was to lift a question ban. I'm not going into, whether the ban was justified or not. I'm going to say this, though: I have seen far, far worse submissions from users, without any evidence of a ban.

The edit was well meant. But, as we know, well meant is often the opposite of well done. That is the case here, too. The edit changed the question from

> Does the Windows API have namespaces?

essentially to (paraphrased by me)

> I know the answer to *that* question already, but let me clarify (without actually clarifying anything).

The initial question was pretty clear:

> I'm a C# programmer, familiar with its practices, and referencing of namespaces within the .Net Framework libraries. Do WinAPI libraries such as User32 have namespaces as well?

just like the answer:

> The Windows API is exposed strictly as a C interface. There are no namespaces in C.

That answer was invalidated by the edit<sup>1</sup>, and the edit did nothing in the way of clarifying the question. Apparently, the OP tried to ask a different question altogether. It's unclear, what that question is, or whether that question is just the result of speculation based off of false premises (like the false premise, that there were namespaces in .NET).

I would suggest to roll back the changes, and ask a new question, once you have built a mental model, that coincides with facts, and allows you to actually ask that question.

---

A note on the proposed [edit to the *answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19101453). That was clearly in conflict with my intent, changing the meaning of the answer. The answer was correct, and I had to reject the edit later on to keep it correct.

---

<sup>1</sup> *The effect then is, that a perfectly valid and correct answer [receives down-votes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable?tab=reputation). The rationale probably goes something like this* "OP already knows this, dumbass. -1"*.*

Comment: "The effect then is, that a perfectly valid and correct answer receives down-votes". Slightly pedantic point: It is not a perfectly valid and correct answer anymore, so the down vote is justified. Doesn't alter the fact that the answerer has been penalised through no fault of his own though.

Comment: @JeremyP: *"It is not a perfectly valid and correct answer **anymore**"* - exactly the point I was trying to make. I'm glad that you agree, that the edit *did* change the question, invalidating a valid answer. This is a typical lose-lose-lose situation. The OP loses, because they still have no answer to their new question. The answerer loses by getting penalized *"through no fault of [their] own"*. The community loses by getting a mismatched Q&A pair.